# What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/synopsis)

> Daniel is a street performer in Chicago. He is shown doing a card
>   trick to an attractive young girl.  The seemingly typical card tricks
>   climax in the side of the John Hancock Center somehow reflecting his
>   card.

here I have two questions to ask: How the climax end in other place;J**ohn Hancock Center**?

& another doubt what does it mean by **somehow reflecting his card**?

Answer (score 1):

This quote is taken from a synopsis of the movie Now you see me. Unfortunately the synopsis doesn't make a very good job of describing the scene.

First the quote:

> Daniel is a street performer in Chicago. He is shown doing a card trick to an attractive young girl. The seemingly typical card tricks climax in the side of the John Hancock Center somehow reflecting his card.

Now let's break that down in terms of what actually happens.

Daniel is performing a card trick at night, outside of the John Hancock center in Chicago. The audience is led to anticipate a *typical* "pick-a-card" type trick. Instead of this, at the *climax* of the trick, Daniel throws the cards into the air and, at the same time, *somehow*, office lights come on in the building in the same pattern as the face of the chosen card - the seven of diamonds.

Once you understand what is being described, the text, which is not that clear, becomes easier to understand. *Reflected* is not actually wrong but, without context, it is possibly misleading.

I've found the scene in question on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_diRgwPCS8)

Answer (score 0):

it means the card tricks reached the climax by relecting the card in his hand onto the side of the John Hacock Center.

**Somehow** means have no idea how he did the trick